# camel route dies in OnCompletion, no indication why

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the following route with an oncompletion section.  When there are errors earlier in the route (caused by bad data in the file), camel does not run all steps in oncompletion.  It seems to run the 1st one and that is it.  So in the route below, the  step gets called and then camel stops.  If I take out the log then sendCompletionEmail() is called and camel stops.

If there are no data errors then all steps in oncompletion are run, and an email is sent.  What am I missing?  Camel is making it to oncompletion when there are data errors.  Why aren't all the steps running?

```
<route id="spreadsheetMilRouteDirect">
    <from uri="direct:csvRouteDirectFile" />
        <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException</exception>
            <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="1" />
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
             </handled>
            <transform>
                <simple>Failed to process record of file - ${header.CamelFileNameOnly} \n\n Reason - ${exception.message}  \n\n Position in file - ${header.CamelSplitIndex} \n\n Record - |${in.body}| \n\n ${exception.stacktrace}</simple>                       
            </transform>
            <to uri="bean:ExternalBAImpl?method=setUnknown" />  
            <to uri="log:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"></to>
            <to uri="smtp://mail1.us.com?to=c@tra.com&amp;from=DEV@tra.com&amp;subject=MFC File Processing - Exception - Failed to process a record of the csv file due to IllegalArgumentException" />
        </onException> 
        <onException>
            <exception>java.text.ParseException</exception>
            <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="1" />
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
             </handled>
            <to uri="bean:ExternalBAImpl?method=setUnknown" />  
            <to uri="log:java.text.ParseException"></to>
            <transform>
                    <simple>Failed to process record of file - ${header.CamelFileNameOnly} \n\n Reason - ${exception.message}  \n\n Position in file - ${header.CamelSplitIndex} \n\n Record - ${in.body} \n\n ${exception.stacktrace}</simple>                         
                </transform>
            <to uri="smtp://mail1.us.com?to=c@tra.com&amp;from=DEV@tra.com&amp;subject=MFC File Processing - Exception - Failed to process a record of the csv file due to ParseException" />
        </onException> 
        <onException>
            <exception>java.io.FileNotFoundException</exception>
            <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="12"  redeliveryDelay="5000" retryAttemptedLogLevel="WARN"/>
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
             </handled>
            <to uri="log:java.io.FileNotFoundException"></to>
            <transform>
                    <simple>Failed to process ${header.CamelFileNameOnly} \n\n Reason - ${exception.message}  \n\n ${exception.stacktrace}</simple>                         
                </transform>
            <to uri="smtp://mail1.us.com?to=c@tra.com&amp;from=DEV@tra.com&amp;subject=MFC File Processing - Exception - Failed to process of the csv file due to FileNotFoundException" />
        </onException> 
        <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
             </handled>
            <to uri="log:java.lang.Exception"></to>
            <transform>
                    <simple>Failure while processing ${header.CamelFileNameOnly} \n\n Reason - ${exception.message}  \n\n ${exception.stacktrace}</simple>                      
                </transform>
            <to uri="smtp://mail1.us.com?to=c@tra.com&amp;from=DEV@tra.com&amp;subject=MFC File Processing - Exception - Failed to process of the csv file due to Exception" />
        </onException> 
        <split parallelProcessing="false" strategyRef="exchangePropertiesAggregatorStrategy" >
            <tokenize token="\r\n"/>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${in.body} regex '^FD_DESC_CD.*'</simple>
                    <to uri="stub:bean:ExternalBAImpl?method=setFileHeader" />  
                </when>
                    <when>
                    <simple>${in.body} regex '^,*$'</simple>
                    <aggregate  strategyRef="aggregatorStrategy" forceCompletionOnStop="true" completionTimeout="3000">
                         <correlationExpression>
                            <constant>true</constant>
                        </correlationExpression>
                        <transform>
                            <simple>Skipped records in file - ${header.CamelFileNameOnly} \n\n Reason - Blank Records ',,,,'.  ${header.CamelAggregatedSize} blank found. </simple>                         
                        </transform>
                        <to uri="smtp://mail1.us.com?to=c@tra.com&amp;from=DEV@tra.com&amp;subject=MFC File Processing - Exception - Blank records not processd"/>
                    </aggregate>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <when>
                        <simple>${file:name} regex 'manual.*.csv'</simple>
                        <unmarshal ref="csv.navcsv.format"/>
                        <to uri="bean:ExternalBAImpl?method=setRate" />
                    </when>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>               
        </split>
      <onCompletion>
            <to uri="log:completion" /> 
            <to uri="bean:ExternalBAImpl?method=sendCompletionEmail" />
            <log message="LOG STEP 2" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="com.mycompany.MyCoolRoute"/>
            <transform>
                <simple>${property[completionEmailMessage]}</simple>
            </transform>
            <log message="LOG STEP 3" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="com.mycompany.MyCoolRoute"/>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${property[completionStatusMessage]} == 'Success'</simple>
                    <to uri="smtp://mail1.us.aegon.com?contentType=text/html&amp;to=chris.hankey@transamerica.com&amp;from=MFCDEV@transamerica.com&amp;subject=MFC File Processing Status - CSV - Success" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <to uri="smtp://mail1.us.aegon.com?contentType=text/html&amp;to=chris.hankey@transamerica.com&amp;from=MFCDEV@transamerica.com&amp;subject=MFC File Processing Status - CSV - Error" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </onCompletion>
</route>
```

Comment: Note: this appears to be a bug in the camel version im using.  Lots of tickets related to oncompletion: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-3372?jql=text%20~%20%22oncompletion%22